# Align an element to the bottom of the parent and center

Tags: html, css

I created a responsive webpage, with a styled `ul` selector to provide a multipane view.

```
<ul class="threepane">
    <li>
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <p>Foo <br /> bar <br /> baz </p>
        <a href="x.html" class="button">More</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <p>Foo <br/> bar </p>
        <a href="y.html" class="button">More</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Section 3</h3>
        <p>Foo</p>
        <a href="z.html" class="button">More</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I won't post the whole styling right now so as not to clutter the post. Let me know if I should do it. This looks like that right now:

[image: current page]

The only problem is the positioning of the buttons - I'd like them to be at one height. So I added this selectors to my styles

```
#about {
    position: relative; 
}

 #about .button {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0; 
 }
```

Unfortunately, now the buttons aren't centered (the left border of the button is in the center of the pane). And of course, if the panes come to display one above another, all buttons are displayed in the same place.

On the other hand, if I change the `#about` selector to `#about ul` or `#about li`, the `ul` block shrinks and the buttons are aligned too high.

All I want is: all buttons should be in one row with the button most close to the bottom. In this case: align height of the second and third button to the first button (but I don't want to hardcode that the first pane is the longest)

How can I achieve it?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good idea to drop IE support altogether. IE11 doesn't support flexbox.

Comment: then apply min-height or fix height

Comment: IE **does** support flexbox, quite well. IE10, not so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that **without** positioning *anything*.

```css
.threepane {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 1em;
}
li a {
  margin-top: auto;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="threepane">
  <li>
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae dolor laboriosam modi ab inventore voluptatum labore quae reiciendis odit totam cum alias quidem minima obcaecati atque ip.</p>
    <a href="x.html" class="button">More</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <p>Foo
      <br/>bar</p>
    <a href="y.html" class="button">More</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <p>Foo</p>
    <a href="z.html" class="button">More</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox like below. It supports IE10 onwards.

```css
* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 
 box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.threepane {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.threepane li {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
          background: yellow;
          position: relative;
  
}
.threepane li p {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.threepane li a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="threepane">
    <li>
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <p>Foo <br /> bar <br /> baz </p>
        <a href="x.html" class="button">More</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <p>Foo <br/> bar </p>
        <a href="y.html" class="button">More</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Section 3</h3>
        <p>Foo</p>
        <a href="z.html" class="button">More</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `position: relative` to the `ul` instead of the `li` and achieve the desired result

**HTML**

```
<ul class="threepane">
    <li>
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <p>Foo <br /> bar <br /> baz </p>
        <a href="x.html" class="button">More</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <p>Foo <br/> bar </p>
        <a href="y.html" class="button">More</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Section 3</h3>
        <p>Foo</p>
        <a href="z.html" class="button">More</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0; 
 }

li {
  width: 32%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.threepane {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

Example : http://jsbin.com/xatihoneze/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<style>
li{
position:relative;
text-align:center;
display: inline-block;
height: 150px;
overflow-y: auto;
}

li p{
display:block;
width:100px;
height:100px;
overflow: auto;
}

li .button{
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```